# Processing shuffle an array in array

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I want to shuffle my array which is in an array, but only the first array

```
String[][] kaarten = {  {"G", "T","1"}, 
                        {"G", "T","2"},
                        {"G", "T","3"},
                        //green triangle
                        {"R", "T","1"},
                        {"R", "T","2"},
                        {"R", "T","3"},
                        //red triangle
                        {"B", "T","1"},
                        {"B", "T","2"},
                        {"B", "T","3"},
                        //blue triangle
                        {"G", "O","1"},
                        {"G", "O","2"},
                        {"G", "O","3"},
                        //green Oval
                        {"R", "T","1"},
                        {"R", "T","2"},
                        {"R", "T","3"},
                        //Red Oval
                        {"B", "T","1"},
                        {"B", "T","2"},
                        {"B", "T","3"},
                        //Blue Oval
                        {"G", "S","1"},
                        {"G", "S","2"},
                        {"G", "S","3"},
                        //green Square
                        {"R", "T","1"},
                        {"R", "T","2"},
                        {"R", "T","3"},
                        //Red Square
                        {"B", "T","1"},
                        {"B", "T","2"},
                        {"B", "T","3"},
                        //Blue Square
                      };
```

So the `{"G", "T", "1"}` needs to stay the same.

I hope you understand what I am seeing, it's kinda hard to explain.

Comment: Oh and please also edit your question to add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: please explain what actually you are looking for.

Comment: I want the array to be shuffled without the array which in it is being shuffled @Raúl

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to create a list of `String[]` and use [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)):

```
List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(values, kaarten);
Collections.shuffle(values);
values.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

will show that `values` was randomly rearranged without modifying the internal `String[]`:

```
[G, O, 3] 
[R, T, 3]
[G, O, 2]
[R, T, 3]
[R, T, 1]
...
```